# Cannot upload a file to a ftp server using C++

Tags: c++, ftp, filezilla

I have this simple code to upload a file to a server, but it seems that it doesnt work, doesn't upload any file(FtpPutFile returns 0). I am using FileZilla Server and this is my code and what FileZilla says:

```
void upload()
{
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet,"127.0.0.1",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,"vbx","pass",INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0,0 );
    FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "c:\\stories.txt", "e:\\text.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
    InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}

(000011)3/27/2011 0:01:53 AM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER vbx
(000011)3/27/2011 0:01:53 AM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for vbx
(000011)3/27/2011 0:01:53 AM - (not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS *******
(000011)3/27/2011 0:01:53 AM - vbx (127.0.0.1)> 230 Logged on
(000011)3/27/2011 0:01:53 AM - vbx (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

Thank you.

edit: `GetLastError() returns: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Comment: What's error checking get you (i.e. check returns and call GetLastError())?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake, yes it returns an error(32): The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the FtpPutFile call?  Odd.  From the lack of an attempt to transfer the file in the server log, I would have guessed it to have failed.

Comment: @vBx: ah, sounds like someone has an open handle to it and prevents read sharing.

Comment: strange, i dont understand why i get this, hmmm

Comment: See if Process Explorer can tell you which process has a handle open to stories.txt.

Comment: could the problem be that at the same time I am writing to the text file ?

Comment: If you're preventing read sharing (I assume FtpPutFile just opens the file for read), absolutely.

Comment: if i change the file, to put another one instead of the one writing in it, i receive a 12003 error "Permision denied" in FIleZilla...I always get this when using ftp, but I dont remeber how i fixed the problem in the past

Comment: That might be related to the specifying the remote file path in the request, as the now-deleted answer suggested.

Comment: ahh, i solved the problem imediately :) when setting in filezilla the home directory, i had to check the Read Write, Delete Append  options for files

Comment: Cool.  Sounds like you just need to solve the sharing violation and you're good.

Comment: @ Peter Huene: thanks for taking time in helping me

Comment: No worries.  I'll answer the question if you don't mind so you can close it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GetLastError() returning ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION (32) for FtpPutFile, it likely means that that there is an open handle to "c:\stories.txt" that prevents read sharing.  If you have this file open in your program, you will need to either allow read sharing in the CreateFile call or close all open handles that prevent sharing so that FtpPutFile can open the file.

Comment: Note: if you were previously writing to the file in question and you opt for allowing read sharing and keeping the handle open, you'll want to call FlushFileBuffers to ensure the writes are flushed to the file.  Of course, if you write to the file on another thread while the file is being uploaded to the server, the contents on the server may not be what you expect.